# NP, NP-complete and Reducibility

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete, decidability

Suppose there is polynomial time reduce from problem $A$ to $B$.

fact $1)$ if problem $B$ is $NP$-hard then Problem $A$ is $NP$-complete.

fact $2)$ if problem $A$ is $NP$-complete then Problem $B$ is $NP$-complete.

fact $3)$ problem $A$ as not hard as $B$.

Can I say fact $(3)$ is true and fact $(1)$, $(2)$ is false because:

the fact $1$ is false because if problem $B$ is $NP$-hard then $A$ can be $P$, or $NP$ or $NP$-complete?

the fact $2$ is false because if problem $A$ is $NP$-complete then problem $B$ can be $NP$-complete or $NP$-hard?

**Is my reasoning correct?**

Comment: I think the best answer to such questions is giving explicit example. "Can be" statement itself requires proof.

Comment: Even non-formal - how do you know "it can be" without examples? Also, $A \in P$ doesn't mean $A$ isn't $NP$-complete...

Comment: I don't see any important difference. You essentially say "it's false that $A$ is necessary $NP$-complete because it may be not". But you need to somehow show that it indeed is possible. Otherwise I can write the same line "it's false that $x^2 + 1 = 1$ implies $x = 0$ because may be $x \neq 0$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1), let both $A$ and $B$ be halting problem. Then $A$ is clearly reducible to $B$ and $B$ is $NP$-hard (any computable problem can be reduced to halting problem in polynomial time), but $A$ isn't $NP$-complete (as it's not in $NP$).

For 2), let $A$ be any $NP$-complete problem (for example, 3-SAT) and let $B$ be halting problem. Then again $A$ is reducible to $B$, but $B$ isn't $NP$-complete.

For 3) - it's unclear what "problem $A$ as not hard as $B$" means.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language, and I don't understand what "problem A is not as more harder than B" means. Can you please describe it in simpler grammar?

Comment: Yes, any problem in P, NP, PH, etc. can be reduced to halting problem in polynomial time.

Comment: @mihaild Can we say "the complexity of problem B is at least the same as the complexity of problem A" (intuitively, problem B is at least as "hard" as problem A, or "problem A is not more harder than B")?

Comment: @RiverLi yes, it's standard expressions, formally meaning "A is reducible to B".

Comment: sorry in $(1)$ you means halting problem is poly time reducible to halting problem?

Comment: @BettyAndersson yes. Any problem is poly time reducible to itself:)

Comment: very thanks. one question if B is NP hard then A is NP hard is false. how I can adopt halting problem like you?

Comment: If you want an example with B NP-hard, A not NP-hard and A reducible to B? There are only two languages we currently know to be not NP-hard - empty language and language of all words. Both are trivially reducible to any standard NP-complete language.

Comment: +1. nice. I means as like as your nice answer make me an example that why we know A is reducible in poly time to  B, if B is NP-Hard then A is NP-hard is false fact? as simple as your nice answer please.

Comment: @BettyAndersson I guess it deserves it's own question already.